# How to write a custom element-wise function in numpy elegantly?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use the np.meshgrid fucntion to do some things on a 2D grid:

```
import numpy as np

def gauss2d(x, y):
    return np.exp(-(np.power(x-np.arange(10), 2) + np.power(y-np.arange(10), 2)) / 2).sum()

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(6))
z = gauss2d(x, y)
```

but got a error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,5) (10,)
```

I can only do it right by a simple nested for loop implementation:

```
z = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        z[i, j] = gauss2d(x[i, j], y[i, j])
```

So, how do it elegantly in a numpy manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [4]: x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(6))                                           
In [5]: x.shape                                                                                  
Out[5]: (6, 5)
In [6]: y.shape                                                                                  
Out[6]: (6, 5)
```

`x` can't work directly with a size 10 array:

```
In [7]: x-np.arange(10)                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cd10c5c1eea4> in <module>
----> 1 x-np.arange(10)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,5) (10,)
```

but by adding a dimension to `x`, making it (6,5,1) it will 'broadcast' with the (10,):

```
In [8]: (x[:,:,None]-np.arange(10)).shape                                                        
Out[8]: (6, 5, 10)
```

Effectively: (6,5,1) (10,)=> (6,5,1) (1,1,10) => (6,5,10)

Then we can do the sum on the last dimension

```
In [9]: (x[:,:,None]-np.arange(10)).sum(axis=2).shape                                            
Out[9]: (6, 5)
```

Alternatively `(x - np.arange(10)[:,None,None]).sum(axis=0)`, putting the (10,) first.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `reshape` first so numpy knows you are working on two numbers every time.

```
In [25]: x = np.reshape(x, [-1, 1])

In [26]: y = np.reshape(y, [-1, 1])

In [28]: def gauss2d(x, y):
    ...:     return np.exp(-(np.power(x-np.arange(10), 2) + np.power(y-np.arange
    ...: (10), 2)) / 2).sum()
    ...:
    ...:

In [29]: gauss2d(x, y)
Out[29]: 26.295857532549885
```